# Windows 7 fails to boot after cloning it into large drive (3 tb), with motherboard supporting UEFI

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi

Situation:

I had ASROCK P67 Pro 3 P2.0 motherboard with 1 tb disc drive with Windows 7 Home Premium x64. I just bought 3 tb disc (Seagate Barracude). I used Seagate disc tool to clone 1 tb into 3 tb with partition resizing (with single partition - not counting that 100 mb Windows partition), than I deatached 1 tb drive (the only remaining is 3 tb).

When I'm trying to boot from "Windows Boot Manager" as 1st boot device, I got `BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc0000001` and when I'm trying to boot from that drive as 1st boot device I got `MBR Boot Failed 1`

I googled a lot and found out that I need to boot in UEFI mode instead of BIOS mode, but I can't find that option anywhere in my UEFI control panel of motherboard.

I also tried to put in Windows 7 cd disc and use "Repair computer", but it failed as well with "This version of Windows is not supported" error message (it's the same disc I've installed from)

What am I missing?

EDIT, as suggested in answer below:

I've changed drive mode from AHCI to IDE and I was able to run Windows repair from CD - it said that it found errors with booting, fixed them all, but after restart it still shows `BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc0000001`. I've noticed also that in boot device order I have now two "Windows Boot Manager" to choose from instead of one

Comment: You say *"Repair computer", but it failed as well*. How did it fail? What error did you get? What behavior did you see during and after the repair?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a bit of a guess here, but it seems a reasonable one.

It isn't completely unreasonable to guess that the BL in `BlInitializeLibrary` stands for *boot loader*. (This would be consistent with Microsoft's internal API naming scheme.)

A little bit of googling says that the error 0xc0000001 can be caused by almost anything, but given the function name, I wouldn't be particularly surprised if it is a load failure in your case. That would abort the boot process.

Your 1 TB drive was most likely partitioned using MBR, which supports drives up to about 2 TB in size, and the Windows boot loader installed was the MBR boot loader because that was what was needed *on that smaller drive*. Your 3 TB drive would likely need to be partitioned using some other scheme for it to be possible to represent its partitions at all. (The 2 TB limit derives from using real or emulated sectors of 512 bytes in size.)

So what is needed likely is to replace Windows' boot loader with one that understands the partitioning scheme in use on the new drive. Normally I would suggest a system repair in such a case, but you say that you already tried that and received an error saying "This version of Windows is not supported" by the media in question, which is rather puzzling if it was indeed the same media that you installed from. (Are you *absolutely sure* about having installed from the same media that you tried to use now?)

The quick and easy solution is to keep using the 1 TB drive as the system disk, and relegate the new 3 TB drive to a data disk. (Note that this doesn't necessarily mean you'll end up with another drive letter; NTFS junction points allow you to use another partition at basically any point in the directory structure, so you should be able to put, say, `C:\Users` on the larger drive. There are some limitations, however; you probably won't be able to put `Program Files` onto the larger drive, for instance.)

The proper solution, if you want to use the 3 TB drive as the system disk, would be to find installation media that allows you to do a repair on the there-present Windows installation. You *could* also reinstall Windows on the new drive, but personally I'd probably find that to be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: I've changed drive mode from AHCI to IDE and I was able to run Windows repair from CD - it said that it found errors with booting, fixed them all, but after restart it still shows `BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc0000001`. I've noticed also that in boot device order I have now two "Windows Boot Manager" to choose from instead of one

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete solution, but I recommend you read the [Windows BIOS to UEFI](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) page. It describes how to convert a Windows installation from booting in BIOS mode to booting in EFI mode; however, it emphasizes using DUET, which is a sort of software version of UEFI that loads like a boot loader. If your motherboard supports UEFI directly, though, you won't need to use DUET and so can ignore those portions of the article. If you started with a BIOS-mode boot, though, some or all of the rest of the article may apply to you.